# How to solve the "local variable 'stressed' referenced before assignment" error?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that recommends the user an activity to do after a short quiz. It takes tries to figure out how the user is feeling and assigns points to different moods depending on how they feel. At the end it recommends an activity depending on how many points the user received in each mood.

In this piece of code I am trying to add 1 to the 'stressed' variable but I keep receiving this error message "local variable 'stressed' referenced before assignment"

Here is my code

```
Questions = [
"Was your day stressful?\n(a) Yes\n(b) No\n(c) Kinda\n\n",
"Do you feel happy?",
"Are you sad?",]

happy = 0
sad = 0
stressed = 0

def question1():
    answer1 = input(Questions[0])
    if answer1 == "a" or "A":
        stressed += 1
        question2()
    if answer1 == "b" or "B":
        question2()
    if answer1 == "c" or "C":
        stressed += 0.5
        question2()

question1()
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As written, your code is not valid Python (indentation issues). Please [edit] your post to ensure it matches the code you're actually using.

Comment: `global stressed`

Comment: Also, `if answer1 == "a" or "A":` is not correct. It should be `if answer1 in ("a", "A"):` or `if answer1.lower() == "a":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stressed was not recognised in your question1() function. Thus you can add

```
global stressed
```

in question1() to make sure it references the stressed variable you created outside the function

```
def question1():
    global stressed
    answer1 = input(Questions[0])
    if answer1 == "a" or "A":
    stressed += 1
    question2()
if answer1 == "b" or "B":
    question2()
if answer1 == "c" or "C":
    stressed += 0.5
    question2()
```